# CSS3 fade in without fade out - one way transition

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to animate my html only with css. A list should fade in, if I add a class ti the element but should immediately disappear, if I remove the class.

I tried several things with transitions in css3. But i seems that all transitions are for both, mount and unmount of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic trick is to remove the transition in the basic class an append it in the `show` class.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#container").toggleClass("show")
})
```

```css
#container {
  color: white;
  background: #357700;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: none;
}

#container.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Show/Hide</button>

<div id="container">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```